# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bilby'

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, bilby

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An example of how to use bilby to perform parameter estimation for
non-gravitational wave data consisting of a Gaussian with a mean and variance
"""
import bilby
import numpy as np

# A few simple setup steps
label = "gaussian_example"
outdir = "outdir"

# Here is minimum requirement for a Likelihood class to run with bilby. In this
# case, we setup a GaussianLikelihood, which needs to have a log_likelihood
# method. Note, in this case we will NOT make use of the `bilby`
# waveform_generator to make the signal.

# Making simulated data: in this case, we consider just a Gaussian

data = np.random.normal(3, 4, 100)


class SimpleGaussianLikelihood(bilby.Likelihood):
    def __init__(self, data):
        """
        A very simple Gaussian likelihood

        Parameters
        ----------
        data: array_like
            The data to analyse
        """
        super().__init__(parameters={"mu": None, "sigma": None})
        self.data = data
        self.N = len(data)

    def log_likelihood(self):
        mu = self.parameters["mu"]
        sigma = self.parameters["sigma"]
        res = self.data - mu
        return -0.5 * (
            np.sum((res / sigma) ** 2) + self.N * np.log(2 * np.pi * sigma**2)
        )


likelihood = SimpleGaussianLikelihood(data)
priors = dict(
    mu=bilby.core.prior.Uniform(0, 5, "mu"),
    sigma=bilby.core.prior.Uniform(0, 10, "sigma"),
)

# And run sampler
result = bilby.run_sampler(
    likelihood=likelihood,
    priors=priors,
    sampler="dynesty",
    nlive=1000,
    outdir=outdir,
    label=label,
)
result.plot_corner()
```

I ran this code

And the error message is this

```
\[Running\] /usr/bin/env python "/Users/sumilee/bilby/examples/core_examples/gaussian_example.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sumilee/bilby/examples/core_examples/gaussian_example.py", line 6, in \<module\>
import bilby
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bilby'

\[Done\] exited with code=1 in 0.068 seconds
```

I know that I had to download the bilby package.
But I already made a virtual environment through the anaconda and set up all the packages.
When I set up the packages, I turned on the virtual environment by laptop's terminal, wrote this on the terminal
'conda install -c conda-forge bilby'
'conda install -c conda-forge gwpy python-lalsimulation'
I once again checked through the terminal whether these packages were installed
Further, I'm using a vscode right now, I connected the virtual environment

I don't want to redownload the packages through the pip packages.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Needs more debugging. Please show what Python is running. E.g., `/usr/bin/env which python` or `/usr/bin/env python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'`. It's unclear that the environment with `bilby` installed is actually executing the script.

Comment: it's telling you bilby isn't installed - use `pip install bilby` in the env you're using to run.

Comment: Are you running the script in VS Code itself? If VS Code is correctly picking up your conda install there should be a bit towards right of the footer on the VS Code window that shows the running Python version with the conda virtual environment in brackets. If you see this, and it does not show the name of the environment in which you installed bilby etc, click on it and see if that environment name is listed.

Comment: Sorry for late. I solved the problem. The reason was I didn't connect the terminal through the vscode to conda. You guys were right. 
Have a nice day!